# clang -Xclang -cc1 -O3 mips.c -emit-llvm , clang error: -emit-llvm cannot be used when linking

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I want to use the clang front-end to convert mips.c to mips.ll which is a llvm IR.

So I use the command:     `clang -cc1 O3 mips.c -emit-llvm`.
A fatal error occurs: 'stdio.h'(which is included in mips.c) file not found.

Then I change the command as following: `clang -Xclang -cc1 O3 mips.c -emit-llvm`. 
Another error occurs: -emit-llvm cannot be used when linking

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As written in the error message, you can only compile when emitting LLVM IR, not link.

Either add `-c` for the bitcode or `-S` for the readable form to your command line:

```
clang -Xclang -cc1 -O3 mips.c -emit-llvm -S
```